# ATtiny85 PWM: why does COM1A0 need to be set before PWM B will work?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, pwm

I want to enable high-speed PWM output on PB4 using an ATtiny85. Having read the datasheet, it appears that the following conditions need to be met:

- PLL and PCK need to be set to enable the high-speed peripheral clock
- The prescaler needs to be set to enable timing
- OCR1B and OCR1C need to be set to choose duty cycle
- PB4 needs to be configured as an output and the compare mode needs to be set using COM1B0/COM1B1
- PWM B needs to be enabled using GTCCR:PWM1B

The code below works - I see PWM output on PB4 and can vary the duty cycle by changing OCR1B - however it only works if I also set COM1A0 in TCCR1. If I don't set COM1A0 then PB4 stays high and no PWM output is generated.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/delay.h>

int main() {
// Enable PLL and async PCK for high-speed PWM
PLLCSR |= (1 << PLLE) | (1 << PCKE);

// Set prescaler to PCK/2048
TCCR1 |= (1 << CS10) | (1 << CS11) | (0 << CS12) | (0 << CS13);

// Set OCR1B compare value and OCR1C TOP value
OCR1B = 128;
OCR1C = 255;

// Enable OCRB output on PB4, configure compare mode and enable PWM B
DDRB |= (1 << PB4);
GTCCR |= (1 << COM1B0) | (1 << COM1B1);
GTCCR |= (1 << PWM1B);

// Why is this necessary?
TCCR1 |= (1 << COM1A0);

while (1) {}

return 0;
}
```

Why is this necessary? The datasheet states that the COM1A bits control OC1A/PB1, which shouldn't have anything to do with OC1B and OCRB

The reason I'm trying to use OC1B/PB4 rather than OC1A/PB1 is that PB4 is not used during ISP while PB1 is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this an old chip? It appears a couple people have also had this problem.

http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=printview&t=119678

Towards the bottom of the thread they concluded it was a hardware issue in the chip that has since presumably been fixed. Your code looks good. I wonder if Atmel ever fixed the issue.

The  [ATtiny85 datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-2586-avr-8-bit-microcontroller-attiny25-attiny45-attiny85_datasheet.pdf) in the Errata (section 27.2.3 / page 213) says:

> 4) **Timer Counter 1 PWM output generation on OC1B – XOC1B does not work correctly**
>   Timer Counter1 PWM output OC1B-XOC1B does not work correctly. Only in the case when the control bits, COM1B1 and COM1B0 are in the same mode as COM1A1 and COM1A0, respectively, the OC1B-XOC1B output works correctly.
>
> **Problem Fix/Work around**
>   The only workaround is to use same control setting on COM1A[1:0] and COM1B[1:0] control bits, see table 14-
>   4 in the data sheet. The problem has been fixed for Tiny45 rev D.

Answer (score 2):

This really stumped me for a while. I've been reading with the data sheet and for the most part, everything you said is correct to me. However, I noticed some potential discrepancies so I'm going to fire these at you and maybe we'll find out what the problem is.

First of all, I checked the TCCR1 register and looked at the COM1A0 bit:

[image]

It is true that by the table, this clearly states  that the COM1A[1:0] bits regard only the OC1A PWM output. Note that at the bottom, it says:

*"In PWM mode, these bits have different functions"*

So I checked out table 12-1.

[image]

The table shows COM1x1 and COM1x0 manipulate the OC1x pin. One would intuitively think that if one is changing the COM1A[1:0], then it would only manipulate the OC1A PWM pin. However, see the text above:

*"When the counter value match the contents of OCR1A or OCR1B, the OC1A and OC1B outputs are set or cleared"*

This seems to suggest that if OCR1A **OR** OCR1B is matched, the OC1A **AND** OC1B outputs are set, or cleared, according to the COM1x[1:0] bits.

So it seems to me that manipulating the COM1x[1:0] bits, provided that the HW is enabled in PWM mode, that these PWM outputs are both influenced at the same time. This is why when you have COM1A[1:0] cleared to '00', table 12-1 says that the PWM outputs are not connected.

Just a thought, perhaps someone more enlightened can critique my logic.